# Using Linkedin's dust.js as rich email templating platform

Tags: node.js, dust.js, email-templates

I want to send rich email to users using nodemailer of **node.js**. But the template engine I want to use is **dust-LinkedIn** template engine.

Do anybody has an idea of using dust.js for email templating or have a working tutorial of it with nodemailer for sending emails. Please share your views.

Comment: Your question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow in its current form, because you haven't stated a specific problem you're having. Node is not an "email sending engine". What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Nodemailer supports templates via [node-email-templates](https://github.com/niftylettuce/node-email-templates).

This package supports, via consolidate, the use of a wide variety of template engines, including Dust. Their [quick-start guide](https://github.com/niftylettuce/node-email-templates#quick-start) includes details.

Install `email-templates` and the engines you wish to use by adding them to your package.json dependencies.

```
npm install --save email-templates
# See https://www.npmjs.com/package/consolidate for a full list of available template engines
npm install --save dustjs-linkedin
```